# How to run a file preview handler through the surrogate host

Tags: c++, winapi, com, ipreviewhandler

According to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/preview-handlers#server-model-options):

> Preview handlers always run out of process. There are two methods of
> implementing this:
>
> 1. A preview handler can be built as an in-process server but run
>    through an out-of-process surrogate host. This is the preferred
>    method. The system provides a surrogate host for this in the
>    Prevhost.exe file. Preview handlers built by this method are not
>    compatible with Outlook 2007 on Windows XP. However, these same
>    handlers will work in Windows Explorer and Outlook 2007 running on
>    Windows Vista.
> 2. A preview handler can be built as a local Component Object Model
>    (COM) server. This is not recommended for several reasons. First,
>    implementation of an in-process server is easier. More importantly,
>    implementation as an in-process server provides greater control over
>    the lifetime of the handler object, which allows for better cleanup
>    and efficiency.

How does a host go about running a preview handler the first way?  I've tried instantiating a preview handler like so, but unlike the preview handler in Explorer, this does not result in the launching of the Preview Handler Surrogate Host:

```
HRESULT PreviewHandlerFromExt(LPCWSTR pszExt, IPreviewHandler** ppph)
{
    WCHAR szCLSID[CLSID_LEN] = { 0 };
    DWORD cchOut = CLSID_LEN;
    HRESULT hr = AssocQueryString(  ASSOCF_INIT_DEFAULTTOSTAR,
                                    ASSOCSTR_SHELLEXTENSION,
                                    pszExt,
                                    L"{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}",
                                    szCLSID,
                                    &cchOut );
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    CLSID clsid;
    hr = CLSIDFromString(szCLSID, &clsid);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    CComPtr<IUnknown> punk;
    hr = punk.CoCreateInstance(clsid, NULL, CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER);
    if (FAILED(hr))
    {
        return hr;
    }

    CComPtr<IPreviewHandler> pPrevHandler;
    hr = punk->QueryInterface(&pPrevHandler);
    if (FAILED(hr) || !pPrevHandler)
    {
        return hr;
    }

    return pPrevHandler.CopyTo(ppph);
}
```

Do you need a different flag for `CoCreateInstance`, or is there some other method you need altogether?  Trying to instantiate handlers for Office files in proc always fails.

Comment: What is the error message of the failure? And is the preview handler officially provided or you wrote it yourself?

Comment: If I try INPROC, then the failure message is "No such interface supported."  And these are the official preview handlers.